# Regarding Quasi-normal modes of black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, perturbation-theory

I am a Ph.D. student working on quasinormal modes of black holes. I am following the paper
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1985ApJ...291L..33S/abstract which is perhaps the first paper on calculating quasinormal modes using WKB approzimation upto 1st order. The basic equation that describes perturbation of a schwarzschild black hole is

d$^2$ $\psi$/dr$_*$$^2$ + {$\sigma$ $^2$ - [1 - (2/r)][$\lambda$/r$^2$ + (2$\beta$/r$^3$)]} $\psi$ = 0
(Equation 7 in tha paper).

From my understanding , the term  [1 - (2/r)][$\lambda$/r$^2$ + (2$\beta$/r$^3$)] represents potential. (Please correct me if I am wrong).
My doubt is

a] from where this potential is coming from ? Is this regge wheeler potential ?

b] Why $\beta$ = 1, 0, -3 for scalar, electromagnetic and gravitational perturbations respectively ?

It would be very helpful if someone could clear my doubts or provide any helpful refernces. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation in question in is the (radial) Teukolsky equation, which describes black hole perturbations. It was derived by [Saul Teukolsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Teukolsky) in [this 1973 paper](https://doi.org/10.1086/152444). One of the remarkable aspects of the Teukolsky equation is that you can write a single equation with just one free parameter $s$ that describes the spin of the perturbing field. When $s=0$ the equation describes (massless) scalar perturbations. When $s=\pm 1$, the equation describes (massless) vector perturbations the most obvious example being the electromagnetic field, and when $s=\pm 2$ it describes (massless) tensor perturbations with the most obvious example the gravitational field. (Any half integer will work.)

In the equation of the paper you mention they use $\beta= 2s+1$ for a scalar (s=0), EM (s=-1) and gravitational (s=-2) perturbation.

The equation in question is specialized to Schwarzschild, but the Teukolsky equation can also be written for perturbations of rotating Kerr black holes.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful, but I could not find this equation in Teukolsky's paper. It may be because Teukolsky has used a different notation of Newman Penrose spin coefficients. Can you tell me the page number in Teukolsky's paper where he has derived the equation in the question?